# java - creating 2D array (matrix) from two 1D arrays

Tags: java, arrays

Given

```
public Object[] suite = {"diamonds","hearts","clubs","spades"};
public Object[] rank  = {"J","Q","K","A"};
```

How do I programmatically achieve:

```
Object[][] card = {{"J","diamonds"},{"Q","diamonds"},{"K","diamonds"},{"A","diamonds}
                  ,{"J","hearts"},  {"Q","hearts"},  {"K","hearts"},  {"A","hearts"}
                  ,{"J","clubs"},   {"Q","clubs"},   {"K","clubs"},   {"A","clubs"}
                  ,{"J","spades"},  {"Q","spades"},  {"K","spades"},  {"A","spades"}
                  };
```

with

```
public Object[][] someMagic( Object[] suite, Object[] rank) {
    Object[][] retVal = new Object[suite.length][rank.length]
    // insert magic here
    return retVal;
}
```

Yes everything needs to be Object, Object[] or Object[][] due to upstream constraints ie. TestNG @DataProvider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of nested loops does the magic but the dimensions of the `retVal` are different:

```java
public Object[][] someMagic(Object[] suite, Object[] rank) {
    Object[][] retVal = new Object[suite.length * rank.length][];
    int i = 0;
    for (Object s : suite) {
        for (Object r : rank) {
            retVal[i++] = new Object[]{ r, s };
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Test:

```java
Object[] suite = {"diamonds","hearts","clubs","spades"};
Object[] rank  = {"J","Q","K","A"};
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(someMagic(suite, rank)));
```

Output (not pretty-printed):

> [[J, diamonds], [Q, diamonds], [K, diamonds], [A, diamonds], [J, hearts], [Q, hearts], [K, hearts], [A, hearts], [J, clubs], [Q, clubs], [K, clubs], [A, clubs], [J, spades], [Q, spades], [K, spades], [A, spades]]

---

However, the shorter spell may be cast using Stream API and `Stream::flatMap` in particular:

```java
public static Object[][] someMagic(Object[] suite, Object[] rank) {
    return Arrays.stream(suite)
        .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(rank).map(r -> new Object[]{ r, s }))
        .toArray(Object[][]::new);
}
```

Comment: For reference, this is called the **Cartesian Product** of two lists.

Comment: `new Object[suite.length * rank.length][2]` may be `new Object[suite.length * rank.length][]`

Comment: @英語は苦手, agreed, fixed

Comment: Ah, streams, I have yet to harness their power. I'll go with this solution. Thanks to all who replied - SO rocks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the solution

```
public class SomeMagic {

    public Object[] suite = {"diamonds","hearts","clubs","spades"};
    public Object[] rank  = {"J","Q","K","A"};
    
    public Object[][] someMagic( Object[] suite, Object[] rank) {

        Object[][] retVal = new Object[suite.length][rank.length];
        
            for(int s = 0; s < suite.length; s++) {
                for(int r = 0; r < rank.length; r++) {
                    System.out.println("s: " + s + ", r: " + r +  ", card[s][r]: " + suite[s] + ", " + rank[r]);
                    retVal[s][r] = new Object[] {suite[s], rank[r]}; 
                }
            }

        return retVal;
        
    } // someMagic
    
    
    public void doIt() {
        Object[][] card = someMagic(suite, rank);
        
        for(int s = 0; s < card.length; s++) {
            System.out.println("s: " + s + "-----------------------------");
            for(int r = 0; r < card[s].length; r++) {
                Object[] item = (Object[]) card[s][r];
                System.out.println("s: " + s + ", r: " + r +  ", card[s][r]: " + item[0] + ", " + item[1]);
            }
        }
        
    } // doIt
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeMagic self = new SomeMagic();
        self.doIt();
    }
    
}
```